# Obtener propiedades de un archivo ASP.NET Razor C#

Tags: c#, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hola estoy haciendo un módulo en **ASP.NET** con **Razor** y **C#** en donde subo a una base de datos un archivo de cualquier tipo, junto con otros datos. Necesito obtener las propiedades de el archivo del lado del servidor ("con **C#**"), para poder anexar estos nuevos datos en mi query para tenerlos en la tabla.
Este es el error que me aparece cuando intento obtener los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código del lado del cliente y del servidor.

```js
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KyoTest(testsoru test) {

  string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

  HttpFileCollection files = test.Files;



  foreach(string fileTagName in files){
  
    HttpPostedFile file = test.Files[fileTagName];
    if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
      
      int size = file.ContentLength;
      string fname = file.FileName;
      int position = fname.LastIndexOf("\\");
      fname = fname.Substring(position + 1);

      string contentType = file.ContentType;
      byte[] fileData = new byte[size];
      file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);


      using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr)) {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru(Name, Wiw, Formato)" +
          " VALUES(@Name,@wiw,@format,@Size,@FName,@Type)";

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query)) {

          cmd.Connection = con;
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", test.name);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", test.wiw);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@format", test.formato);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", size);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", fname);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", contentType);
          con.Open();
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
          con.Close();
        }
      }


    }
  }


  return View(test);
}
```

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("KyoTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
<table class="table table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Customer Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.formato, new { type = "file" })
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender: </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.wiw, new List
      <SelectListItem>
        { new SelectListItem{Text="India", Value="India"}, new SelectListItem{Text="China", Value="China"}, new SelectListItem{Text="Australia", Value="Australia"}, new SelectListItem{Text="France", Value="France"}, new SelectListItem{Text="Unites States", Value="Unites
        States"}, new SelectListItem{Text="Russia", Value="Russia"}, new SelectListItem{Text="Canada", Value="Canada"}}, "Please select")
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
}
```

Muchas gracias a todos por tu apoyo y su tiempo :)

 Este es mi ajax que cambié y con el que trato de ejecutar el mismo método de C#

```js
< script >
  function trymeplz() {
    var object = {};
    object.namePro = $("[id*=name]").val();
    object.file = $('#format').prop("files")[0];
    object.wiw = document.getElementById("wiw").value;

    alert("{'namePro' : '" + object.namePro + "'," +
      "'file' : '" + object.file + "' ," +
      "'wiw' : '" + object.wiw + "'" +
      "}");

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: '@Url.Action("KyoTest", "Home")',
      data: "{'namePro' : '" + object.namePro + "'," +
        "'file' : '" + object.file + "' ," +
        "'wiw' : '" + object.wiw + "'" +
        "}",
      success: function(response) {
        alert("at least Ajax looks fine" + response);
      },
      Error: function(response) {

        alert("something got wrong" + response);
      }
    });
  } <
  /script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class=row "">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" placeholder="NombreDeProyecto" id="name" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Formato</td>
            <td>
              <label>Formato: </label> <input type="file" id="format" />
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Wiw</td>
            <td>
              <p>
                @Session["Wiw"]
                <input type="text" class="hidden" id="wiw" value="@Session[" WiW "]" />
              </p>
            </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" onclick="trymeplz()" name="name" value="trymeplz" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Además de lo que dice @Xique asegúrate de recibir objetos en el objeto `test.Files`, el error que te muestra el IDE es porque estás intentando hacer uso de un objeto nulo ;)

Comment: Hola grácias por sus comentarios Xique no fue el "enctype" , lo agregué pero sigue igual. @Flxtr sabes cómo podría segurarme de insertar esos datos dentro de mi objeto, efectivamente .Files parece estar vacio. Aunque estoy seguro que antes de que empezara a obtener las propiedades del archivo si estaba pasando datos, porque puedo insertarlos sin problema en la base de datos ... alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Supongo que el problema viene porque en el código de la vista no aparece en dónde agregar esos archivos, por lo tanto al recibirlo en el Controlador te va vacío

Comment: Del lado del servidor HttpFileCollection files = test.Files; me pide usar el atributo File me imagino probio de HttpFileCollection, si trato de pasarle algo como test.formato.File me marca error, tampoco puedo hacer HttpFileCollection files = test.formato; igual me da error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de revisar tu código a detalle, me encontré con unas cosas por arreglar.

Código de la vista:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Código del Controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KyoTest(testsoru test, HttpPostedFileBase[] files) 
{
    string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)  
    {
        //...Aquí va el resto de tu código
    } 
}
```

Comment: Interesante, no sabía se podían enviar varios archivos en el mismo campo. :)

Comment: En este ejemplo se muestra claramente, que no siempre es necesario usar el _model binding_. Si en la vista se usa `@Html.TextBox("files", "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })`; no es necesario incluso que sea parte del modelo.

Answer (score 1):

Muchos comentarios en tu solución, así que trataré de irme paso a paso.

-En Asp .Net MVC existe lo que se llama model binding (no necesariamente se utiliza siempre), lo cual consiste básicamente en convertir el valor enviado desde los campos html de la forma a las propiedades con el mismo nombre en el objecto. 
Así pues, si tienes un campo html del tipo input (*con name = "formato"*)

```
<input class="form-control" id="file" name="file" type="file" value="">
```

al hacer el model binding en el action método, el valor que viene en la propiedad del objeto llamada 'file'
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-Como ya te comentaron, al enviar archivos tienes que indicar que la forma html enviar bytes agregando la parte del enctype:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("KyoTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ ...
```

-Muy probablemente vienes de Asp .Net, por aquello de que estas usando

```
HttpFileCollection files = test.Files;
```

en Asp .Net MVC los archivos son del tipo HttpPostedFileWrapper.

```
public HttpPostedFileWrapper file { get; set; }
```

--Por ultimo, te dejo un código que creo te puede ayudar a entender (en él incluso utilizo bootstrap para darle mejor vista):

La vista:

```
@model UploadFiles.Models.testsoru

@using (Html.BeginForm("KyoTest", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Customer Details</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.formato, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.formato, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.file, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.wiw, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.wiw, ViewBag.List as List<SelectListItem>, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

El método de acción:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult KyoTest(testsoru test)
    {
        string constr = "Data Source=DMX87025;Initial Catalog=DB_PCC;Integrated Security=True";

        HttpPostedFileWrapper file = test.file; //No es necesario lo pongas en una variable, pero lo pongo para mostrar el tipo de dato

        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            int size = file.ContentLength;
            string fname = file.FileName;
            int position = fname.LastIndexOf("\\");
            fname = fname.Substring(position + 1);

            string contentType = file.ContentType;
            byte[] fileData = new byte[size];
            file.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, size);

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                string query = "INSERT INTO Testsoru(Name, Wiw, Formato)" +
                  " VALUES(@Name,@wiw,@format,@Size,@FName,@Type)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {

                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", test.name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wiw", test.wiw);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@format", test.formato);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Size", size);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", fname);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", contentType);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        return View(test);
    }
```

El modelo, por si hace falta:

```
public class testsoru
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string formato { get; set; }
    public string wiw { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper file { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hola probé tu código pero no obtengo lo que necesito aún, para empezar me sigue diciendo que lo que mando al servidor es **Null** lo marca justo aquí ** if (file.ContentLength > 0)** otra cosa es que tu estas llamando al modelo de los objetos como un dropdown, yo no quiero nada de eso solo quiero insertar los datos  y para mi file y formato son lo mismo, el que me interesa guardar en este caso es formato. Grácias por tu ayuda, siento que ya estoy muy cerca :)

Comment: Si nos pudieras mostrar como tienes tu código actual, pudiéramos atacar tu actual problema.

Comment: Pues esta examente igual al tuyo del lado del servidor, del lado de front en este momento estoy pasando todo por ajax, hasta ahí hay problema el error esta en C# , me dice 'NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PCotiza-compras.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. '  Cambié el front pórque tu estas llamando la info de la bd a través del modelo y yo solo quiero insertarlo sin jalar nada

Comment: Alguien comento que ese error me esta pasando porque creo que mando el objeto vacio, pero no sé como asegurarme de que el objeto este lleno.

Comment: Es correcto, parece que el error se origina en la vista y en tu llamada de ajax. Nos compartes el código de la vista, por favor?

Comment: Listo lo he agregado hasta arriba :) gracias